# Querying database with an array of related objects in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, relationship, querying

I would like to query some offers by skills from my database with laravel.

The relationship between an offer and its skills is a belongsToMany relationship.

How to get all offers that match an array of skills from the database ?

To be clearer here is some code I started to write :

```
        $skills = Input::get('skills');
        $offers = Offer::with(
            array(
                'skills' => function($query){
                    // here I'd like to select skills from array $skills
                    $query->where(?????);
                }
            )
        )->get();
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Use whereIn with array

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects

```
$skills = Input::get('skills');
$offers = Offer::with(array('skills' => function($query) use ($skills){
                    $query->whereIn('skill', $skills);
                }))->get();
```